# Union of open balls around rationals - topologically

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Assuming $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb N  } $ is an enumeration of all the rational numbers, let $F$ be a subset of $ \mathbb R $
$$ F = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} (q_n - \frac{1} {2^n},q_n + \frac{1} {2^n}) $$
Prove of $F \subsetneq \mathbb R $

My idea:
$F $ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R $, since it contains $\mathbb Q $.
The n-th open interval "becomes very small very fast",
and, if all these intervals were to be disjoint (which is not true, of course), then the sum of the measures of each interval would be finite (using the convergence of the geometric series $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1} {2 ^n} $).
Though, I suspect the exercise requires an explicit (or constructive) proof. I found it in a general topology book, and I don't know even if I can use arguments from measure theory.
I saw other answers to a similar problem but using Lebesgue measure. Is it possible not to use it?

Anyway, what should I be considering? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without any result from  measure theory we can show that if $[a,b]$ is covered by  a **finite** number of open intervals then $b-a$ cannot exceed the sum of then lengths of the intervals. [Use induction on the number of intervals].  If $\mathbb R =\bigcup (q_n-\frac 1  {2^{n}},q_n+\frac 1  {2^{n}})$ then, by compactness $[-2,2]$ is covered by  a finite number of the intervals $(q_n-\frac 1  {2^{n}},q_n+\frac 1  {2^{n}})$ which leads to the contradiction $4 \leq 2$ since $\sum \frac 2 {2^{n}}=2$.